# Counting childs only with given class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to count only childs with given class?

The code, and how the nth-children (or nth-of-type) counts children:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child yes">###</div> <!--odd -->
  <div class="child yes">###</div> <!--even -->
  <div class="child">###</div>     <!--odd -->
  <div class="child yes">###</div> <!--even -->
  <div class="child yes">###</div> <!--odd -->
</div>
```

And the css what works not the way i itended to

```
#parent .child.yes:nth-child(odd) {
  color: red;
}

#parent .child.yes:nth-child(even) {
  color: green;
}
```

But id like it to count as:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child yes">###</div> <!--odd -->
  <div class="child yes">###</div> <!--even -->
  <div class="child">###</div>     <!--skip this odd-->
  <div class="child yes">###</div> <!--odd-->
  <div class="child yes">###</div> <!--even -->
  <div class="child yes">###</div> <!--odd-->
  <div class="child yes">###</div> <!--even -->
  <div class="child yes">###</div> <!--odd-->
</div>
```

Ive tryined also using `:not()` operators, but no luck.. should it be done via javascript?

EDIT:
For a fiddle link, to see different cases [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/6mox7j45/)

So it should reset the counter of odd/evens after there will not be `.yes` class
as:

odd, even, odd, ###, odd, even, ###, odd, even

Accepted answer by DanL, via jQuery

```
var parent = $('#parent');
var counter = 1;
parent.children('.child').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('yes') ) {
      if ( counter%2 == 0 )
          $(this).css('color', 'red');
      else
          $(this).css('color', 'green');
      counter++;
    } else {
      counter = 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: With CSS...no, not really. What exactly are you trying to do...why do you need to count these?

Comment: You're looking for `nth-of-class`...which doesn't exist.

Comment: If you want a css solution, so why the javascript tag added to the OP?

Comment: Yes Paulie, i was looking for that, but sadly i must accept that it doesnt exists..

The js tag is there because i dont mind using javascript while css is not possible

Comment: I believe I understand your question correctly. Please check my answer/fiddle and let me know if this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you want to loop through all `child yes` classed elements, but skip any `child` classed elements that do not also have the `yes` class. If this is incorrect please let me know and I will update my answer. Assuming this is true, try something like this with jQuery.

```
var parent = $('#parent');
var counter = 1;
parent.children('.child').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('yes') ) {
      if ( counter%2 == 0 )
          $(this).css('color', 'red');
      else
          $(this).css('color', 'green');
      counter++;
    } else {
      counter = 1;
    }
});
```

Sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mr8vnbso/3/

Comment: This one is almost good, but when there will be 3 `.yes` div-s before the div without it (4th), the 5th div will have the wrong color (since it will be the 4th in that array, but in a case like that, i should be odd)

Comment: So you want to reset the odd/even counter upon reaching a .child with no .yes? Just want to be clear.

Comment: With the 4th element not having "yes", it currently outputs: green, red, green, black, red. Are you saying in this case it should output: green, red, green, black, green, red?

Comment: If you can, update your original question with examples. For instance, tell us what the outputted colors SHOULD be for a given set of HTML. I think that will help everyone better understand your exact intentions.

Comment: yes, it should reset the counter would be nice way to say it
so output would be
green, red, green, black, green red
or
green, red, black, green, red, green

Comment: Updated, try it now.

Comment: Thats a great way to do this, i accept as an answer, thank you

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

With Jquery (not pure JS)

```js
var n = $(".child.yes").length;
$("span").text("There are " + n + " red divs.");
```

```css
.child {
  color: green;
}
.yes {
  color: purple;
}
.child.yes {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child yes">###</div>
  <!--odd -->
  <div class="child yes">###</div>
  <!--even -->
  <div class="child">###</div>
  <!--odd -->
  <div class="child yes">###</div>
  <!--even -->
  <div class="child yes">###</div>
  <!--odd -->
</div>
<span></span>
```

Comment: It appears as if he wants to loop through ONLY the elements matching both the "child" and "yes" class. Your code simply attaches red text to all "yes" classed elements.

Comment: The CSS styles red elements but the JQ selects elements with both classes. Updated CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = $('#parent').children();
var arrayLength = array.length;
```

Does this work? Or do you want something like:

```
var item = $('#parent').children().eq(n); // n is a number
var item = $('#parent').children().first();
var item = $('#parent').children().last();
```

For the CSS part you don't need to add the parent element:

```
.child.red {
  color: red;
}

.child.red {
  color: green;
}

<div id="parent">
  <div class="child red">###</div> <!--odd -->
  <div class="child green">###</div> <!--even -->
  <div class="child red">###</div>     <!--odd -->
  <div class="child green">###</div> <!--even -->
  <div class="child red">###</div> <!--odd -->
</div>
```

Comment: Be careful there's no jQuery tag in the OP.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I know, but without using it, he just makes his life harder.

Comment: i dont mind, now there is.. ill take a look for that, since i dont mind using js or jQuery lib. I would have done it by using js anyway, was just curious about capabilities of css

Answer (score 0):

What you want will be available in the future, as it is a new CSS4 feature.

[:nth-match](http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/structural-pseudo-class/)